# What is the use of the "dup2_x2" instruction in JVM bytecode?

Tags: java, jvm, javac, jvm-bytecode

Java has a `dup2_x2` instruction which, according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dup2_x2), has the following behavior:

> Duplicate the top one or two values on the operand stack and insert the duplicated values, in the original order, into the operand stack.

Does `javac` produce bytecode with this instruction? What are its potential use cases?

Comment: Careful. That's from FORTH. You're getting into the weeds. `: sumn DUP 1+ * 2/ ;`

Comment: You can find out how the instruction is *actually* used within the JVM etc by searching the OpenJDK codebase.  Of course, other programming languages target the JVM platform, and their compilers, etc may emit this bytecode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, the following code

```java
public static Long example1(Long[] array, int i, long l) {
    return array[i]=l;
}
public static long example2(long[] array, int i, long l) {
    return array[i]=l;
}
```

compiles to

```
  public static java.lang.Long example1(java.lang.Long[], int, long);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: lload_2
       3: invokestatic  #1        // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
       6: dup_x2
       7: aastore
       8: areturn

  public static long example2(long[], int, long);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: lload_2
       3: dup2_x2
       4: lastore
       5: lreturn
```

See, [demo on Ideone](https://ideone.com/Djif5W)